# Can i inherit the twisted.web.http.Request.requestReceived?

Tags: python, twisted, nimbus, cumulus

Can i inherit the twisted.web.http.Request.requestReceived ??

In the comment, said that "This method is not intended for users".

I has inherited the rawDataReceived and it like this:

```
def rawDataReceived(self, data):
    self.resetTimeout()
    if len(data) < self.length:
        self.requests[-1].content.send(data)
        self.length = self.length - len(data)
    else:
        self.requests[-1].content.send(data[:self.length])
        self._finishRequestBody(data[self.length:])
```

the `self.requests[-1].content.send(data)` will send the data in another http connection. In fact, i use the httplib here.

All goes well, but it doesn't work at the last step in allContentReceived. And it's req.requestReceived(command, path, version).

So can i inherit this method requestReceived. Or where is it go wrong?

my code is here. You can download it if you want help me.

http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=569597&uk=926264233

Comment: that link doesn't work for me.  can you edit your question to include the code you want help with?  You almost certainly don't need to subclass or modify `Request` so long as you're working with `HTTP/1.1` compliant peers; and certainly not just to ferry data from one connection to another; least of all with `httplib`.